# Don't understand when a service can be recreated when using START_NOT_STICKY

Tags: android, android-intent, service, kill

The documentation says that when you use START_NOT_STICKY:

> If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, do not recreate the service unless there are pending intents to deliver.

What does it mean pending intents in this context? When you use startService(Intent), the method onStartCommand() is executed immediately. There aren't any pending intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you use startService(Intent), the method onStartCommand() is executed immediately

Not necessarily. `onStartCommand()` is called on the main application thread. Hence, it will process only one `Intent` at a time. However, other threads can call `startService()` many times while `onStartCommand()` is still processing one `Intent`. If that occurs, those additional start requests are queued up, and `onStartCommand()` will be executed for each of those in turn.

Comment: If there are pending intents to deliver, will the service execute onStartCommand as many times as the number of pending intents?

Comment: @MartíSerra: It should, yes. There are always edge cases (e.g., user force-stops app from Settings).